# Jquery Tabs hide and show

Tags: jquery, html, tabs

I need help to show the Pressed tab.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
  } );
  </script>
<div id="tabs">
                <center><a href="#tabs-1"><img src="link.png"></a> 
            </div>
                <a href="#tabs-2"><img src="link.png"></a> 
            </div>
            </center>
</center><br><center><div id="tabs-1">
```

Now I see all tabs. How can Hide 1 tab and only show when press tab 1?

Comment: This is not complete code. And it is seriously malformed. Opening and closing tags are missing or not matching. Please refer to JQueryUI page and follow the simple examples to understand how it works here: http://jqueryui.com/tabs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how can Hide 1 tab and only show wen press tab 1

In order to hide tab 1 you can write:

```
$('#tabs-1').hide();
```

where [hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) is the jQuery method used to hide the tab 1.

Instead if you need to set the default active tab you can use the [active](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#option-active) option.

```js
$("#tabs").tabs({
   active: 0
});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><center><a href="#tabs-1"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff&text=1"></a></center></li>
        <li><center><a href="#tabs-2"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff&text=2"></a></center></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <p>111111111111111111</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
        <p>22222222222222222</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I mean this : http://www.directupload.net/file/d/4839/mzbmdokw_png.htm

Tab 1 = Default Show Tab
Tab 2 = when pressed then tab 1 hide and tab 2 show

Comment: @user3211952 Snippet and answer updated. I don't know if I understood correctly. Let me know and I'll give a look. Thanks